# Ruby on Railsでjqueryのバージョンを確認したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery

初歩的な事で申し訳ないんですが、タイトルの通りRuby on Railsで使われているjqueryのバージョンを確認したいのです。
デバッグ時のソースからjquery.jsを開いたときに頭に書いてある
jQuery JavaScript Library v1.11.1
がバージョンと考えていいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Jquery::Rails::JQUERY_VERSION` で、確認することが出来ます。

```
pry(main> Jquery::Rails::JQUERY_VERSION
=> "1.11.2"
```

Answer (score 0):

参考情報
http://www.buildinsider.net/web/jqueryref/002
> 現在利用しているjQueryのバージョンを確認するには？

> ...
>   現在利用しているjQueryライブラリのバージョンを、JavaScriptコードから実行中に確認する方法を説明する。また、ライブラリのバージョンの使い分けや、旧バージョンの入手方法も紹介。
>   ....
>   現在利用しているjQueryのバージョンを確認するには、$.fn.jqueryにアクセスします。
>   ...